# Find() on EF is forcing me to specify the type in the call for a generic method

Tags: c#, entity-framework

**Disclaimer**: The code I'm going to paste below is a sample of my issue.  It's not the real code, for the purposes of the question it's not necessary to post the full code as I've isolated the issue.

I have a generic method for calling "find" on a dataset as shown below.

```
private static void GenericFind<TEntity, T>(T keys) where TEntity : class
{
    using (var dc = new AMSContext())
    {
        var ea = dc.Set<TEntity>().Find(keys);
    }
}
```

This works perfectly if the key is an integer, but doesn't work if it's a composite key, type: object[].

If I specify that it's an object in the find call, then it works.  Shown below

```
var ea = dc.Set<TEntity>().Find(keys as object[]);
```

Here are the calls to the method

```
GenericFind<wf_tasks, int>(1); // Works
GenericFind<WfTaskEa, object[]>(new object[] { 7, 1 }); // Doesn't work unless I force the type in the find call
```

Now, I can add a test to see the type of T and force the object type.  But I'm curious if there is any other (better) way.

**Edit: My current working solution**

```
var entity = typeof (T).Name == "Object[]"
    ? dc.Set<TEntity>().Find(keys as object[])
    : dc.Set<TEntity>().Find(keys);
```

Comment: Don't worry. No one can ever find their keys. :-)

Comment: @clcto, no, find doesn't have that functionality.

Comment: What is "doesn't work"? Compile-time, run-time error? What error?

Comment: The find call fails because the number of parameters don't match.

Comment: What happens if you use dc.Set<TEntity>().Find(keys as T) ?

Comment: @JacobProffitt, good question.  I'm unable to implement that.  In that usage T needs to be specified as a reference class, which means I can't pass in `int` as `t` because `int` isn't a reference type.

Comment: Ah. Good point. How about dc.Set<TEntity>().Find((T)keys) ?

Comment: @JacobProffitt, no good.  Still the same issue.  I think I'll just have to stick with my fix.  It's not as generic as I would like it to be. But it works.

Comment: Yeah, that's what Stilgar's answer would indicate. If the overload is chosen at compile time, then you really do have to give enough info to the compiler so it knows which overload to choose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overload resolution is done at compile time. This means that the compiler must choose the overload before it knows the generic type. Since there are no generic constraints it chooses the object type which kind of makes sense.

Now of course in this particular example you don't need a generic type for keys and you can just make it params object[] keys like the actual Find method does.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  This isn't the actual implementation, it's just a code isolation to show the issue.  In the actual implementation the key type is specified in the class definition, not at the method.  But it's easier to show the issue in code snippets with what I displayed in the question.

Comment: You can still make the find method params T[] and always call the Find overload with an array even if there is just one key.

Comment: The find method is just one that I created for the question.  The actual method doesn't take in the key parameter. The key parameter is a class member that's initialized during construction.  FYI: I'm building on top of an existing architecture.  So I have limited options on what I can/can't change.

Comment: To be clear, I agree 100% with what you're saying, it's definitely what I would rather do.  It's just not something that I can easily implement.